# Why changes not applied when I use justify content in parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers, display

i'm learning css and in flex , i try to use justify content to center my content but it's not working

And this is my code

```
 .top-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    margin: 20px 60px 20px 60px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .single-section{
    flex-grow: 1;
    width:20%;
  }
  .img-h{
    width: 35%;
  }
  .img-top-container{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .single-section > h3{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
```

My png files are big , so i use .img-h for make them smaller,
`.top-container` is parent div
`.single-section` is child div
`.img-top-container` is the img

But `justify-content : center;` in .single-section and other selectors not working, what is the problem?

Comment: I have to make my code smaller to prevent site errors

Comment: can you add the related html?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="top-container">
        <div class="single-section">
            <div class="img-h">
                <img class="img-top-container" src="../source/image/digijet.png">
                <h3>دیجی جت</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is several code like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).